# How can I clear the entry text when doing pull down refresh?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an entry on the top of a page and a listview on below of that. When doing pull down refresh I want to clear the text on that entry.

Following is my entry code:

```
<Entry 
    x:Name="SearchEntry"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    PlaceholderColor="Black"
    FontFamily="Bold"
    TextColor="Black"
    Placeholder="Search a Directory"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you use MVVM and have a `ViewModel`.
Create and bind a property of type string from your `ViewModel` to `Entry.Text`. Inside refresh method set this property to `null` or `string.Empty`.

Example:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // TODO: Handle INotifyPropertyChanged correctly
    public string EntryTextProp { get; set; }

    public async Task<?> UpdateList()
    {
        // ...
        EntryTextProp = null;
        // ...
    }
}

<Entry 
    x:Name="SearchEntry"
    Text="{Binding EntryTextProp}"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    PlaceholderColor="Black"
    FontFamily="Bold"
    TextColor="Black"
    Placeholder="Search a Directory"/>
```

Comment: This is not working, I tried EntryTextProp = null; EntryTextProp = string.empty; and EntryTextProp = "";

Comment: Remove async keyword from your command lambda expression and also put IsRefreshing=true; in first line.

Comment: I guess your comment is not related to my answer?

Comment: Right, it was meant for question not your answer, excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

**Updating the complete code here, this might help others.**

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _entrytext = "";
    public string EntryText
    {
        protected set
        {
            if (_entrytext != value)
            {
                _entrytext = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EntryText");
            }
        }
        get { return _entrytext; }
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                IsRefreshing = true;
                EntryText = null;
                MyList();
                IsRefreshing = false;
            });
        }
    }
}



  <Entry 
    x:Name="SearchEntry"
    Text="{Binding EntryTextProp}"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    PlaceholderColor="Black"
    FontFamily="Bold"
    TextColor="Black"
    Placeholder="Search a Directory"/>
```